# active admin gem (name error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have this classes.

user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  has_many :berichten
end
```

category:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :berichten
end
```

Berichten :

```
class Berichten < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :bericht, :user
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I did first : rails generate active_admin:resource users
And I see this output :  create  app/admin/users.rb

Then I did : ails generate active_admin:resource category
And I see this output :

```
 home/roelof/tamara/tamara_site/app/admin/users.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Users (NameError)
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:182:in `block in load!'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:182:in `each'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:182:in `load!'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/application.rb:205:in `routes'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin.rb:79:in `routes'
    from /home/roelof/tamara/tamara_site/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
    from /home/roelof/tamara/tamara_site/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `reload_routes!'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:34:in `reload!'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:61:in `block in attach!'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__3584427286517482665__prepare__2286595675940506716__callbacks'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/roelof/tamara/tamara_site/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /home/roelof/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

How to solve this one?

Roelof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do `rails generate active_admin:resource user` instead of `rails generate active_admin:resource users` (user vs. users).

The way you did it, active_admin searches for a `Users` class which of course doesn't exist.

So delete `app/admin/users.rb` and run the command above.